# Привидение типов и арифметические операции в универсальных функциях

Tags: rust

Решил написать нечто универсальной функции range, которая заполняла бы вектор любим примитивным типом - i32, u32, f32 и тд - и возвращала бы его. Проблема состоит в приведении типов и арифметическими операциями над ними. Как универсальный тип Т приводить к конкретным типам и обратно, чтобы можно было сравнивать тип Т с другими типами и проводить над ними арифметические операции?

```rust
use std::ops::Add;

fn rngg<T>(start: T, stop: T, step: T) -> Vec<T>
    where T: Add<Output=T> + Copy + PartialOrd {

    let mut v: Vec<T> = Vec::new();

    if step == 0 {
        let mut tmp = 0;
        while tmp < step {
          v.push(tmp);
          tmp = tmp + (1 as T);

        }
    }
    else {
        let mut tmp = start + step;
        while tmp < stop {
            v.push(tmp);
            tmp = tmp + step;
        }
    }
    v
}


fn main() {

    let r = rngg(1.0, 18.0, 2.0);
    for i in &r {
        println!("{:?}", i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Здесь проблема в том, что целочисленные литералы получают определенный тип (`i32`) и не совместимы с обобщенным типом `T`. Их можно преобразовать к типу `T`, потребовав, чтобы для этого типа существовали преобразования `Into` или `TryInto`:

```rust
use std::convert::TryInto;
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::ops::Add;

fn rngg<T>(start: T, stop: T, step: T) -> Vec<T>
where
    T: Add + Copy + PartialOrd,
    i8: TryInto<T>,
    <i8 as TryInto<T>>::Error: Debug,
{
    let zero = 0i8.try_into().unwrap();
    let one = 1i8.try_into().unwrap();

    let mut v: Vec<T> = Vec::new();

    if step == zero {
        let mut tmp = zero;
        while tmp < step {
          v.push(tmp);
          tmp = tmp + one;
        }
    }
    else {
        let mut tmp = start + step;
        while tmp < stop {
            v.push(tmp);
            tmp = tmp + step;
        }
    }
    v
}
```

С `Into` код попроще, но набор подходящих типов чуть-чуть сужается из-за того, что безошибочное преобразование из `i8` в `u8` невозможно в общем случае и соответствующим образом параметризированный `From` не определен.

Если хочется совсем обобщенного подхода, можно воспользоваться, например, библиотекой [num](https://docs.rs/num) или определить свой типаж для примитивных типов:

```rust
trait FieldIdentities {
    const ZERO: Self;
    const ONE: Self;
}

impl FieldIdentities for i32 {
    const ZERO: i32 = 0;
    const ONE: i32 = 1;
}
```